# Migrating to CDI 1.2 WELD Exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

After migrating to CDI 1.2 in Liberty, my application started throwing a WELD exception that I am unclear how to solve:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001334: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DataHandler with qualifiers @Any @DataHandlerBean WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
  - Session bean [class com.ibm.blueargus.feed.PathSquadHandler with qualifiers [@DataHandlerBean @Any]; local interfaces are [DataHandler],
  - Session bean [class com.ibm.blueargus.feed.DownAccessPointDataHandler with qualifiers [@DataHandlerBean @Named @Any]; local interfaces are [DataHandler],
  - Session bean [class com.ibm.blueargus.feed.ATTTicketDataHandler with qualifiers [@DataHandlerBean @Any]; local interfaces are [DataHandler],
  - Session bean [class com.ibm.blueargus.feed.WirelessClientDataHandler with qualifiers [@Named @DataHandlerBean @Any]; local interfaces are [DataHandler]
```

This occurs where I am selecting a bean based on custom annotation value - a requirement of the application to be able to execute a particular EJB implementation based on criteria stored in the database. How do I update my code to work with CDI 1.1 and still allow for a dynamic selection of EJB implementation based on a custom qualifier value? Is there a better approach that would give me the same general feature?

**The Qualifier Specification**

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface DataHandlerBean {

   String value();

}
```

**The Annotation Implementation:**

```
public class DataHandlerBeanQualifier extends AnnotationLiteral <DataHandlerBean> implements DataHandlerBean {

    private String value;

    public DataHandlerBeanQualifier (String value) {
        this.value=value;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

**The EJB Interface:**

```
@Local
public interface DataHandler {

    public void extractData (Monitor monitor, DataFeed dataFeed) throws Exception;

}
```

**Sample EJB Implementation:**

```
@Stateless
@DataHandlerBean("downAccessPointHandler")
public class DownAccessPointDataHandler implements DataHandler {
```

**Business Logic EJB Causing the Problem (snippet):**
The value in monitor.getDataHandler() is used to select the appropriate EJB implementation to pass control for further processing.

```
@Stateless
public class DataScannerImpl implements DataScanner {

    public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DataScanner.class.getName());

    @Inject
    @Any
    private Instance <DataHandler> dataHandlerInstance;

    private String processMonitorList(List <Monitor> monitorList, boolean forceLoad) {
        ...

        try {
            dataHandler = dataHandlerInstance.select(new DataHandlerBeanQualifier(monitor.getDataHandler())).get();
            dataHandler.extractData(monitor, dataFeed);
            monitor.setDataFeed(dataFeed);
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.warn("Could not execute dataHandler: " + monitor.getDataHandler(), e);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

This all worked fine in my previous production environment on WebSphere v8.5. The web application was using the CDI 1.0.

**Current Environment (server.xml):**

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbPersistentTimer-3.2</feature>
    <feature>ldapRegistry-3.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrsClient-2.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.1</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Comment: This is for migrating to CDI 1.2

Comment: What is your deployment structure? What WAR/EAR/JAR do you have there and which bean resides in which archive? Technically speaking your approach looks  valid; did your previous Liberty version use Weld as CDI impl or owb? There may be some impl-details you are running into (visibility of bean across complex archives being one of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a typo in the database values that were causing values of `monitor.getDataHandler()` to return bean names that did not actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a `@Producer` method that will be injected with the 4 classes implementing the `DataScanner` interface
The 4 classes must be annotated with 4 different annotations
Based on your business logic, the producer will select and "produce" the right implementation
Then you can directy inject `"DataScanner"` where you need it:

```
@Inject
private DataHandler dataHandlerInstance;
```

This is described in the [Weld documentatiion here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.4.7.Final/en-US/html/injection.html#_qualifier_annotations)

In the doc, the producer choses between 2 implementation of the `"PaymentProcessor"` interface: `"@Synchronous PaymentProcessor syncPaymentProcessor"`and `"@Asynchronous PaymentProcessor asyncPaymentProcessor"`